# Combine_split from Software Foundations exercise

Tags: coq

I'm working through exercises of course [CIS 500](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis500/current/index.html). Currently on [MoreCoq](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis500/current/sf/MoreCoq.v).

This is where I'm stuck:

```
Theorem combine_split : forall X Y (l : list (X * Y)) l1 l2,
  split l = (l1, l2) ->
  combine l1 l2 = l.
Proof. intros X Y l. induction l. 
 Case "[]". intros.  inversion H. (*stuck*)
```

Goals are

```
 2 subgoal
    Case := "[]" : String.string
    X : Type
    Y : Type
    l1 : list X
    l2 : list Y
    H : split [] = (l1, l2)
    H1 : admit = (l1, l2)
```

What to do next? What is this `H1 : admit = (l1, l2)` thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split` function is given as an exercise in an earlier chapter (Poly). The reason you have the `admit` term in your context is that you haven't solved that exercise in your copy of Software Foundations.